# Make TeamCity always publish artifacts

Tags: teamcity

I'm surprised I can't find any documentation about this, but anyway...

Sometimes my TeamCity build hangs, and I end up needing to stop it. The build process produces several log files on disk, which TeamCity then publishes as build artifacts. However, if I stop the build, then TeamCity refuses to publish the logs:

```
Build was interrupted. Artifacts will not be published for this build
```

The files still exist on disk, it's just that TeamCity doesn't publish them any more. This is particularly exasperating since I really, *really* need to see what's in those logs so I can work out why the build hung in the first place.

Is there some way I can force TeamCity to always publish the build artifacts, even if I have to abort the build?

(I've seen several questions asking how to *stop* TeamCity publishing artifacts if the build fails, so I'm a bit puzzled as to why my setup isn't doing this already, but anyway...)

PS. I realise I can just manually log into the build server to see the logs, but kind of the whole point of TeamCity is to automate stuff like that for me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TeamCity has no way of Publishing on a stopped build, which is different than a failed build. Stopped builds are more like a killed process, whereas failed builds are a non-zero exit code.

Instead, I recommend configuring TeamCity so that you don't have to stop a build. There are two options to enable: [hanging build detection](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Configuring+General+Settings#ConfiguringGeneralSettings-buildOptions) and the "[it runs longer than](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Failure+Conditions)" build failure condition. Both should help TeamCity automatically terminate the build rather than you having to stop it.

This way, you will get a failed build rather than a stopped build, and your artifacts should publish.

Comment: Well, in fact there is a way. You can publish artifacts with help of last build step, for example, using this meta-runner: https://github.com/JetBrains/meta-runner-power-pack/tree/master/artifacts-publisher. For this build step you can set execution policy to "Always, even if build stop command was issued".

Comment: Hanging build detection sounds like it might do what I want. I guess then the question is "how do I stop TeamCity estimating that my build will take 17 seconds when the last 50 runs have all taken half an hour?"

Answer (score 4):

I think enabling hanging build detection is a good idea in general (you can set a failure condition on a build taking longer than *n* minutes to finish), but if you are interested in the *artifacts* that have been created so far by a build that is eventually stopped/hanging, the following may be useful:

You can output [TeamCity service messages](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Script+Interaction+with+TeamCity#BuildScriptInteractionwithTeamCity-artPublishing) to immediately publish artifacts. These artifacts will remain available also when a build is stopped. Example:

```
##teamcity[publishArtifacts '/tmp/logfile => logs']
```

This will make sure the file `/tmp/logfile` is published into artifacts directory `logs`.

An additional advantage is that you will have these artifacts available on the build's artifacts tab right away, which could help decide if a build should be cancelled or not.

Comment: This is a worthy idea. However, the artifacts that I'm after are log files which are continuously written to right up until the very end of the build. I'm not completely sure about Linux file access semantics, but wouldn't publishing the logs early just mean I get an incomplete copy?

Comment: The docs state that 'the message should be printed after all the files are ready and no file is locked for reading'. I think you should be able to eventually (re)publish the complete log file when a build it not hanging or stopped, and also with a different artifact name (see the docs on artifacts paths). But you will typically not be able to get the log contents 'up to the hanging activity' because you need to output the service message first to get the log file published.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be last 'Command Line' step of the build
with option 'Execute step: Always, even if build stop command was issued'
which will output publish artifacts directive?